# Need access to a var in another file, not sure how to do it

Tags: ruby, pry

I am creating a hangman game, which at this point will only be played in pry/terminal. I have 4 files:

words_array.rb - big word array

words.rb- word class

game.rb - game class

main.rb - uses methods from words/game and plays the game

In my main.rb file I call create a new game. It takes an arg of an array of words.

```
    require 'pry'
    require_relative ('./words_array.rb') 
    require_relative ('./word.rb') 
    require_relative ('./game.rb') 

    game = Game.new(some_words)

    game.start_game

    while !@game.over?
        puts "Please guess a letter"
        user_letter = gets.chomp
        game.guess(user_letter)

            if game.over?
                game.over_message
            end

        game.render
    end

   binding.pry
```

My problem is that after requiring all my files in pry, and they all seem to loading successfully (including the words_array.rb)  I get an error when it hits/ game = Game.new(some_words) /telling me that some_words is undefined

```
main.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `some_words' for main:Object (NameError)
```

some_words is the array of words (and the only thing in) the words_array.rb file, which was successfully loaded into pry. Why is it not recognizing it, or is there something I should be doing besides requiring it in pry if I want to use it in the main.rb file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `some_words` is out of scope in your program where you are calling it. Just because you are requiring the `words_array.rb` file does not mean the `some_words` variable is in scope and accessible. You should post the beginning of your `words_array.rb` file, showing how you are defining it. Just leave out the huge list of words.

Are you using a module in your file?

```
Module GameWords
  WORDS = %w(dog cat chair ....
end
```

Then when you `require 'words_array'` you can get the array by calling:

```
game = Game.new(GameWords::WORDS)
  # returns ['dog', 'cat', 'chair'....
```

you can do a simpler form just using a constant:

Your words_array.rb can just be:

```
WORDS = %w(dog cat chair ....
```

and you can use it like:

```
game = Game.new(WORDS)
```

Comment: I am still a newb as you can probably tell (lol) - and this is awesome, I will try both ways (is one a better practice than the other?)! I just defined it as I normally would inside my word_array file: some_words = %w( a bunch of words)

Comment: I would say the simplest answer is the best for now. But you should really get into reading up on Modules and MixIns. Since you are just returning the array the simple form is easiest. And yes, your `%w(...` form is better than `[...]`.

Comment: I meant as far as defining it as a module, or a constant, which is better in general? I  defined it as a constant and it worked!So simple and sweet! I have a lot of reading and experimenting to do in general as a newb, lol, and I definitely intend to. But for now on to the next error! thank you so much :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant the constant was simpler. But I also always forget about the `%w` form for arrays which is also simpler. Module is good if you want to have all sorts of other things like methods added to your code. I would HIGLY recommend the code school.com ruby courses. Some are free but well worth the $25 for a month of practice with them.

Comment: Thanks Beartech! I have done a little of codeschool's 'ruby bits' actually, so I am familiar with them - they are awesome! I only got about 2 months of study in on Ruby before I enrolled in a class (in-person class) that is has just starting teaching Ruby (we did Javascript first), so hopefully I will learn more about modules and Constants etc...I just LOVE Ruby!! Thanks again for your help, you folks make SO an awesome resource for newbs like me to learn ;)